# "Я не знаю кто вы и знать это не желаю"

Tags: запятые

Где в этом предложении надо поставить запятые?

Answer (score 3):

Правильно так:

> *Я не знаю, кто вы, и знать этого не желаю.*

Придаточное ***кто вы*** обособляется.